# How to record specific URL with Selenium IDE after clicking any link or button

Tags: selenium-ide

Selenium IDE version: 2.9.0

Consider my Base URL is http://www.example.com/ and there are some links in the page, say a, b, c and so on. After clicking those links the URL becomes as follows:

http://www.example.com/a
http://www.example.com/b
http://www.example.com/c

and so on.

I want to record those absolube URLs with Selenium IDE after clicking each specific link. How can I do that with Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 0):

storeLocation is what you're looking for:

> storeLocation(variableName) Generated from getLocation()
>
> ```
> Returns:
>     the absolute URL of the current page
>
> Gets the absolute URL of the current page.
> ```

Comment: How can I set the option of storeLocation during recording my tests with Selenium IDE? I want the URL recorded for each page.

Comment: You have to explicitly add it where & when you want it.